# Uploading a file to hdfs through hdfs API results in file getting appended and prepended with signature

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My goal is to upload a file, this is what my code looks like:

```
headers = {
    'Some_Auth_Stuff': _get_ca_cert(ROLE),
    'Host': host,
}

files = {'upload_file': file}

params = (
    ('op', 'create'),
    ('permission', '755')
)

r = requests.put(
    'https://proxystuff.hostname.com/fs%s' % hue_path,
    headers=headers, files=files, params=params)

if r.status_code == 201:
    return True
return False
```

and I'm uploading this file:

```
i am a test file
```

I get a 201 response, which is great but when I look at the file, it looks like so:

```
--04dc34a8a49d4b83878473d6d78e683d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_file"; filename="testfile"

i am a test file

--04dc34a8a49d4b83878473d6d78e683d--
```

Am I missing something when it comes down to uploading content? Any way to disable the file from getting stuff prepended and appended?

EDIT: 
If I use this curl command it works fine

```
curl -c cookie -b cookie -T "test.txt" "https://proxystuff.hostname.com/fs/user/stupidfatcat/test.txt?op=create&permission=755" -H "Some_Auth_Stuff:blahblah" -H "Host:someotherhost_with_hadoop.com:4443"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying some stuff out, if I changed it to

```
headers=headers, data=file.read(), params=params
```

and I set the Content-Type to plain/text it works fine, seems like it doesn't like file param.